# How to send parameters to a web page .asp with Webclient C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, httprequest, webclient

I am trying to send parameters to the following web address:

**http:// mu.magdalenaperu.com/reset200.asp**

I catch the headers from the web browser, doing the process manually.
[HeaderReQuest&Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KZjD.jpg)

It also has the parameters within the request
[Parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwuOY.jpg)

The code that I am trying to send the parameters to is the following.

```
var sUrl = new Uri(@"http://mu.magdalenaperu.com/reset200.asp");

using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    var values = new NameValueCollection();
    values["userchr"] = "IIHoruSII";
    values["username"] = "IIHoruSII";
    values["password"] = "IIHoruSII";

    var response = wc.UploadValues(sUrl, "POST", values);
}
```

I tried with almost all the functions of the WebClient: UploadValues, UploadString, but I always have the following error:

**Error in remote server: (503) Server not available.**

I do not think it is a problem of the service state, but the way I use it, I think it has to do with credential issues or the way the server requires the header to access.

Thanks for your time and sorry for the bad english

Comment: I think the 503 is related to CloudFlare. The website you mentioned is protected by CloudFlare against DDOS attacks, and CloudFlare might think that your script is not a valid browser. See http://superuser.com/questions/888507/problems-with-wget-to-a-cloudflare-hosted-site-503-service-unavailable